# Enforce topology rule over a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, file-geodatabase, topology

I have a couple of shapefiles, the first one is a set of points, while the second one is a set of lines. I need to regularize the shapefiles in order to be able to generate a graph (adjacency list / paths) out of them later.

The set of lines has many dangles, with both [undershoot](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/undershoot) and [overshoot](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/search) problems. I want ArcGIS to mark the suspect points and possibly offer me a correction to apply, on an individual basis.

I've seen the tutorial "[Using geodatabase topology to fix line errors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m600000037000000)", which seems to go where I want.

However, in order to create a "topology" with a "Must Not Have Dangles" rule, I need a "geodatabase".
I'm very new to GIS systems, and I'm trying to figure out a way to convert my shapefile to a geodatabase. I did the following

1. open ArcCatalog
2. click Connect Folder to connect the folder with my shapefiles
3. right click on connected folder, New, File Geodatabase
4. right click on created geodatabase, New, Feature Dataset
5. right click on created feature dataset, New, Feature Class
6. added the shapefile with lines (I used the Import button while creating the new Feature Class - see first screenshot below).
7. right click on the feature dataset (not the feature class), New, Topology
8. follow the tutorial

However, after adding the "Must Not Have Dangles" rule, and running Validate, I am told there are no errors. I can see there are errors, there are obvious dangling lines, so why aren't they detected?

[image: New Feature Class]

When I'm finished creating the topology, I get this warning:

[image]

This is the final result:

[image: Final result]

Comment: In New Feature Class wizard the last step has an Import button. I used that. See the image I added (edited OP). Is that enough?

Comment: I don't know about the attribute table, but using import > feature class seems to have done the trick. Any suggestion on how to get the program to suggest for corrections?

Comment: The tutorial you linked to covers under/overshoot correction pretty well (error inspector/fix topology tool), and those methods/manual editing will give you the highest level of control. You could consider the [Integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000) or [Snap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000007000000) tools, but those come with data alteration risks (not all dangles are necessarily errors depending on your data). Otherwise I'm not sure what you mean by 'suggest for corrections'.

Comment: Have you built the topology? Errors aren't generated in dirty areas until you build. You can export dangles from your shapefile directly using Feature Vertices to Points (Advanced license) with the Dangles option, though there is not default tool to assist in inspecting them. Though Chris is right, you haven't actually loaded your features just the table.. right click on the feature class and select 'Load Data' to use the simple data loader to import your features into the empty feature class (hit next, next..) then build your topology (right click on topology and select 'build')

Comment: @ChrisW The point is I actually have 2 layers, so if a line of the lines layer ends up in a point of the point layer, then it shouldn't be marked as a dangle. Any way to put an OR between the rules? Like "line must end over a point of the other layer OR must end over another line"?

Comment: It's *dangle* not *dongle*; a *dongle* is a software key (physical device) that works with licensing software, mostly USB now but they used to be serial and parallel. There is no 'or' in topology rules.. there is a rule 'must fall on endpoint of' that will validate your points but not except them.. hence exporting the error points then remove the ones that coincide, then visit the error points.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson No idea what you mean by "built the topology". Please specify the program and the menu items to click (I can't find the ones you mentioned). BTW Haha, typo.

Comment: Right click on the topology in ArcCatalog then select 'build', or use the geoprocessing tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Validate_Topology/0017000000nw000000/ after you include the feature classes and define the rules it should offer to build it (Would you like to build the topology now yes/no), but if you include features after creation or modify the data the 'dirty' (modified) areas need to be built/validated to check the features with the rules.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson No such thing as 'build' when right clicking the topology. There's only 'validate' and a few others. What about the other command to run on the shapefiles?

Comment: So far as I know, it isn't possible to do *or* combinations of rules. You have to run both rules (and yes, endpoint must be covered by is one and the other you'd need). You'd get false positives, which is why you have to go through them all manually (note you can mark errors as exceptions, which should hold until the topology is rebuilt). A line covered by a point would excuse it from dangle, but I imagine you'll have a lot of other lines that don't dangle but aren't covered by a point either.

Comment: It must be Validate, I haven't touched a topology since ArcGis 9.0... I found out they weren't so helpful (there's no *OR* in the rules) back then it was 'build'. Feature Vertices to Points http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003p000000 will also give you your dangles, which you spatial join with a very small tolerance against your 'good' points and remove the matches. I ended up writing my own undershoot/overshoot tool in C# to find them a few years ago and haven't played with geodatabase topology since (map topology on the other hand is quite useful)

Comment: @ChrisW ok, then I think I'll have less false positives running the no dangles rule only. Thanks for the tip about exceptions. What about the "rebuilding topology" thing? Do you mean "re-validate"?

Comment: That would likely be true. You can always have your point layer loaded and if you see a point on the dangle just mark it as an exception. I can definitely see that generating fewer false positives. And I didn't *mean* revalidate, though I'm not sure because I haven't run one in a while and can't remember what resets exceptions. It might actually be re-validating, or it might preserve them until you modify the topology (add a new rule for example). Or it might not reset them ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shapefiles do not support topology directly, as you have discovered. The data must first be imported in to a geodatabase, and specifically a feature dataset within that geodatabase. If you need to continue on in shapefile form, you'll have to export it back out once you're done topology checking and editing.

The answer to the actual/original question is that you had not imported any geometry to the feature dataset that was participating in the topology. Your step six created a new, blank feature class and the `Import` button you used only brought in the fields from your shapefile, not the actual lines. This is what the message in your second screenshot indicates (topology is valid, but there are no actual features participating).

To do that you need to right-click the feature dataset and rather than choosing `New`, choose `Import > Feature Class` (multiple or single depending on if you want to bring the lines and points in at the same time, but note everything in a feature dataset must be in the same coordinate system) and select the line shapefile. This will import the actual line data into the feature class within the feature dataset.

Comment: Thanks. I don't get the "Dangle errors" bookmarks described in the tutorial though. Any idea about that?

Comment: You would think that ArcGis would have an inbuilt 'visit these' tool; it was the first tool I wrote (in VBA) with 8.3, then the first to get updated to VB6 in 9.0 and (hopefully finally) the first AddIn I wrote. You would need to create your own AddIn or open the topology error dialog and click on each in turn.

Comment: @Agostino I'm pretty sure those are just bookmarks included in the tutorial data to get you to the right area where you can see some examples. Once you've validated the topology, you just click the Error Inspector button and it should pop up a window that lists all the errors (may have to hit Search Now to get the list to populate). Note you need to be in an Edit Session. You can right-click a specific error in the list and choose zoom to. Michael I got a surprise when I discovered the 'step through' tools I'd been using where I last worked were actually custom. So useful in lots of cases.